# Formatting problem from string to Datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to parse a string with the `datetime` standard library module and then display it.

When I try this code, the output looks correct:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> endDate = datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-05-03", '%Y-%m-%d').date()
>>> print(endDate)
2022-05-03
```

But it changes if the `endDate` is put into a list or tuple:

```
>>> print([endDate])
[datetime.date(2022, 5, 3)]
```

Why does the output have the "datetime.date" text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> endDate = datetime.strptime("2022-05-03", '%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

When you printed the date object, it used `str` representation of the date object.

```
>>> str(endDate)
'2022-05-03'
```

When you included that in a container and printed it, the container internally uses [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) representation of the object

```
>>> repr(endDate)
'datetime.date(2022, 5, 3)'
```

---

[`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function by default converts all the objects passed to it to a String with `str`.

> All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like str() does

---

To understand this better, we can create a class which implements both `__str__` and `__repr__` functions like this

```
>>> class Test:
...     def __str__(self):
...         return "TEST_FROM_STR"
...     
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return "TEST_FROM_REPR"
...
```

Now, we can create instances of that class and print them separately and with list, like this

```
>>> Test()
TEST_FROM_REPR
>>> [Test()]
[TEST_FROM_REPR]
>>> print(Test())
TEST_FROM_STR
>>> print([Test()])
[TEST_FROM_REPR]
```